# How to count how many times a heading appears in a ConTeXt document?

Tags: sectioning, context, counters

I have a book containing hundreds of activities for teachers. Each activity is designated with `\section{Activity title}`. `\section` is never used for anything else.

I need some way to count how many times `\section` appears in the document. Is there some built-in counter or some other way to get this value?

Answer (score 6):

When your goal is to show the value of the last `section` you can use the `\headnumber` command but when you're interested in the number of `section`s use the `\someheadnumber` command instead.

```
\setuphead
  [section]
  [conversion=r]

\startbuffer[headnumber]
    \starttabulate
    \NC first   \EQ \headnumber          [section] [first]   \NC\NR
    \NC current \EQ \headnumber          [section] [current] \NC\NR
    \NC last    \EQ \headnumber          [section] [last]    \NC\NR
    \TB
    \NC first   \EQ \somenamedheadnumber {section} {first}   \NC\NR
    \NC current \EQ \somenamedheadnumber {section} {current} \NC\NR
    \NC last    \EQ \somenamedheadnumber {section} {last}    \NC\NR
    \stoptabulate
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\dorecurse{3}
  {\expanded{\section{Section \recurselevel}}
   \getbuffer[headnumber]}

\stoptext
```